# Git: detect changes made during moving block (diff the removed and the added block)

Tags: git, diff

Imagine you're reviewing code changes. One has moved a function from one file to another. The commit shows two files, one with a block removed and another with a block added.

How can I, with Git, make a diff of both blocks to see the changes made within that block of code?

Simplified, minimal diff example:

```
+++ a/modules/foo.js
--- b/modules/foo.js
@@ -314,15 +314,12


-function foo() {
-   returns 42;
-}


+++ a/modules/bar.js
--- b/modules/bar.js
@@ -271,82 +271,85


+function foo() {
+   returns 43;
+}
```

There's a slight change. I'd like to compare both blocks against each other to see this:

```
 function foo() {
-   returns 42;
+   returns 43;
 }
```

I don't want to detect *whether it moved* but I want to see *the difference in the moved block* (that you already recognized as move).

Currently I slice the interesting blocks of code out of the old and new files, store them in temporary files and compare them manually, but I'd like to do this with a tool instead.

So far I would create my own program or script to do this automatically, but I wonder whether this is possible with Git already.

Answer (score 0):

This answer does not fully address your expected output/workflow but it will address the requirement to track changes made along with movements.

It utilizes the copy detection (`-C`) in `git blame`. In contrast to `-M` this switch will detect copies with slight changes.

Take this history:

```
9f3c95c Moved isApplicable() from Foo => Bar
cff47ee Added bar.js
e0efec3 Added foo.js
```

`isApplicable()` moved, it produces this blame (only relevant lines shown):

```
$ git blame -C 9f3c95c3 -- bar.js
cff47ee4 bar.js (John Doe 2017-01-13 20:28:51 +0100 36)           },
cff47ee4 bar.js (John Doe 2017-01-13 20:28:51 +0100 37) 
e0efec3b foo.js (John Doe 2017-01-13 20:18:51 +0100 38)           isApplicable: function(){
e0efec3b foo.js (John Doe 2017-01-13 20:18:51 +0100 39)                   if (!this._depends) {
e0efec3b foo.js (John Doe 2017-01-13 20:18:51 +0100 40)                           // no depends expression defined, default to "yes, it's applicable"
9f3c95c3 bar.js (John Doe 2017-01-13 20:26:47 +0100 41)                           return false;
e0efec3b foo.js (John Doe 2017-01-13 20:18:51 +0100 42)                   }
e0efec3b foo.js (John Doe 2017-01-13 20:18:51 +0100 43) 
e0efec3b foo.js (John Doe 2017-01-13 20:18:51 +0100 44)                   // pass the survey model and the expression
e0efec3b foo.js (John Doe 2017-01-13 20:18:51 +0100 45)                   return Evaluator.evaluate(this.model.toJSON(), this._depends);
e0efec3b foo.js (John Doe 2017-01-13 20:18:51 +0100 46)           },
e0efec3b foo.js (John Doe 2017-01-13 20:18:51 +0100 47) 
cff47ee4 bar.js (John Doe 2017-01-13 20:28:51 +0100 48)           render: function(){
```

The move commit is only shown in line 41 since a `return true;` changed to `return false;` along with the move. The other lines related to `isApplicable()` are labeled with the commit `e0efec3b`, which is the one that introduced them initially (the filename column also designates the original filename).

A pure `blame`, on the other hand, would look like this (only relevant lines shown):

```
$ git blame 9f3c95c3 -- bar.js
cff47ee4 (John Doe 2017-01-13 20:28:51 +0100 36)          },
cff47ee4 (John Doe 2017-01-13 20:28:51 +0100 37) 
9f3c95c3 (John Doe 2017-01-13 20:26:47 +0100 38)          isApplicable: function(){
9f3c95c3 (John Doe 2017-01-13 20:26:47 +0100 39)                  if (!this._depends) {
9f3c95c3 (John Doe 2017-01-13 20:26:47 +0100 40)                          // no depends expression defined, default to "yes, it's applicable"
9f3c95c3 (John Doe 2017-01-13 20:26:47 +0100 41)                          return false;
9f3c95c3 (John Doe 2017-01-13 20:26:47 +0100 42)                  }
9f3c95c3 (John Doe 2017-01-13 20:26:47 +0100 43) 
9f3c95c3 (John Doe 2017-01-13 20:26:47 +0100 44)                  // pass the survey model and the expression
9f3c95c3 (John Doe 2017-01-13 20:26:47 +0100 45)                  return Evaluator.evaluate(this.model.toJSON(), this._depends);
9f3c95c3 (John Doe 2017-01-13 20:26:47 +0100 46)          },
9f3c95c3 (John Doe 2017-01-13 20:26:47 +0100 47) 
cff47ee4 (John Doe 2017-01-13 20:28:51 +0100 48)          render: function(){
```

The move commit is shown as one block since Git sees it as an addition made in `9f3c95c3`.

`git blame -C <REV> -- <FILE>` also works for movements within one file.

The `-C` switch can be specified multiple times to expand the tracing to all files in that commit or all commits found. The man page says:

> `-C|<num>|` 
>   In addition to -M, detect lines moved or copied from other files that were modified in the same commit. This is useful when you reorganize your program and move code around across files. **When this option is given twice, the command additionally looks for copies from other files in the commit that creates the file. When this option is given three times, the command additionally looks for copies from other files in any commit.**

(Emphasis mine.)